# How can I transfer image data between next.js pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on an Instagram clone (Just because I want to learn more about Next.js) and I want to manage the image uploads. Just want the user to upload his image and redirect it to the "create new post" page. The thing is, I don't know how to send the image between pages. I thought of doing a rest API to temporarily store the image and retrieve it, but that seems to be far too complicated. Does anyone have any idea of how I can implement this? I'm using Router from next.js if that helps.

Comment: Why not make an ````<Image />```` component and pass it around?  It doesn't sound like you are trying to properly imitate the upload, store, and retrieve process.  Are you just wanting easy access to the image for UI testing?  If it's a practice in global state management, I would look into ````redux```` or ````React Context````

Comment: Yes, I want to upload the image, edit it, add a comment, upload it to a database and then have it on the feed. That's why I don't make an static object to pass around.

Comment: You said you thought of doing a rest API but opted out, so how are you going to imitate the CRUD processes?  If you're trying to act as if you have already returned the images from the ````database````, I would read up on ````React Context````.  Store an array of images (links to them either locally or URL) explicitly in a global state manager, pass them around as ````props```` and render them. If you are trying to mock the CRUD interaction, simply modify that array as need be.  Doing a quick mockup of ````React Hooks```` will be quicker than ````redux````.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways depending your needs. You can try one of these.

- Use React Context or a state management tool.
- When routing from Page A to Page B, pass your data with querystring. Mask it with "as" prop if you dont want it to be shown on URL. If data is too big; pass it as a Blob URL. Then read query on the second page.
  https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush
- Use localStorage. This is probably shortest way.

Comment: After a lot of researching I finnaly did it with React Context and with createURL. I had my image inside an object that later will be assigned to React Context, so whenever I wanted to use it I could just make an url with crerateObjectURL. Thanks for your reply, I think I learned something new.